# Just trying to understand some code

Tags: function

and good evening,
i have just come across the following code:
void showButtons(boolean mode)
    {

```
    int state = (mode) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;

    l.btn1.setVisibility(state);
    l.btn2.setVisibility(state);
    l.btn3.setVisibility(state);
    l.btn4.setVisibility(state);
}
```

and i not sure how this works exactly, will be grateful for any explanation, thanks in advance. (specially the int state line).

Comment: Greetings. Are you a programmer? I'm guessing you're referring mostly to the ternary expression( ? : )

Comment: yes, i was referring to the ternary expression, i think the comment just below really clarified it all. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The function sets the Visibility of `btn1`, `btn2`, `btn3`, and `btn4` (probably buttons) to `VISIBLE` or `GONE` depending on input.

`showButtons(true);` sets Visibility `VISIBLE`.

`showButtons(false);` sets Visibility `GONE`.

The top line, `int state = (mode) ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;` sets the value `state` to `View.VISIBLE` if `mode` is true, or `View.GONE` if `mode` is false.
It uses an operator called the "conditional operator", which is a little like an if...then...else.  It works like:

```
variable = test_value ? answer_if_test_true : answer_if_test_false;
```